# Installing MSI to ASP.NET Core App Service Windows Container

Tags: docker, msi, windows-server-core, windows-installer, azure-app-services

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2019 to develop a ASP.NET Core 3.1 app running in Docker for Windows.  I'm having a few problems with this.  I need to host an endpoint to start and stop a service and provide some health check info.  The services are installed from a third-party MSI (I'd love to just copy files over, but we don't want to run it unsupported, plus it's files and registry changes).  The basic (dotnet/sdk, /core, and /aspnet) images are based on Nano Server so don't support MSI/msiexec.  I've tried a large number of images to find one that supports ASP.Net Core plus msiexec (Server Core), but it seems like only the large images fit our needs (8+ GB vs <500MB for the Nano ones).  Is there another possibility here?  At this point, I can't even get the build to work consistently.  Files will build but not end up in the final image, and if they make it I can't seem to hit them (trying ports 80/443, 5000/5001, or the actual Docker-exposed ports, with localhost or the container's IP address).  It's getting pretty frustrating!  I'd love any help.

1. Finding a reasonably-sized image that supports ASP.net Core 3.1 and msiexec
2. Build process to properly publish and copy files to the final image
3. Service to be accessible from outside the container.

Current dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# INSTALL dotnet
ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/c37ece76-1305-4042-a9e6-58e7cb1b0bf6/75c20ff59335e370985b4f03fa637fcb/aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.18-win-x64.exe /symedical/
ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7d09d7c0-8902-4467-9268-d7f584923cde/eddcb12257e68b030bc1b4baf9a68681/dotnet-runtime-3.1.18-win-x64.exe /symedical/

RUN C:/symedical/aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.18-win-x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart && \
    C:/symedical/dotnet-runtime-3.1.18-win-x64.exe /install /quiet

ARG InstallerSrc="dist/installers/ThirdPartyClientServices.msi"
ARG InstallerDest="/install/"
ADD ${InstallerSrc} ${InstallerDest}

ARG InstallerSrc="dist/scripts/"
ADD ${InstallerSrc} ${InstallerDest}

RUN powershell -file "c:\dist\scripts\install-msi.ps1"
######

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Distribution/Distribution.csproj", "Distribution/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Distribution/Distribution.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Distribution"
RUN dotnet build "Distribution.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Distribution.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Distribution.dll"]
```